# gitosis change server

Tags: git, gitosis, git-branch

I installed a fresh instance of gitosis, and also have an old one.

What do I have to do to move the repos from the old to the new server? Clone on the new server?

What do I have to change on the developer computers, to switch the remote branch? Or do they need to clone again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the address of the remote "origin" to the new location in your local checkout and push. You can change the address using `git remote` or you can edit `.git/config` directly.

Comment: Thanks, god answer. Can you tell me also how to transfer the full repro with all branches from the old to the new giosis server?

Comment: If you have access to both filesystems, you could just copy everything and be done with it. Otherwise, perhaps it would work to set up both remotes in parallel and try to 'push' branches from origin to the other remote. I've never tried it though. If you don't have too many branches, you could always just check them out individually and push each one to the new repo.

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy all the repository directories to the gitosis's directory. Then you can grant access (read or write) to users by editing gitosis-admin repository.